# Keep getting error from AjaxControlToolkit

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Getting following error from AjaxControlToolkit.
How to resolve it.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].


Stack Trace: 



    [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
       System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
       System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +34
       System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
       System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
       System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +16
       System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
       AjaxControlToolkit.ScriptEntry.LoadAssembly() +27
       AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.IsScriptCombinable(ScriptEntry scriptEntry) +25
       AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.OnResolveScriptReference(ScriptReferenceEventArgs e) +277
       System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterScripts() +269
       System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnPagePreRenderComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e) +124
       System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e) +121
       System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1155



    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: My eyes hurt. Read up on how to ask questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Add more information. Paste some page section, configs, describe how you added ajaxcontroltoolkit to the project.

Comment: This is my first question, so next time i'll explain briefly.

I installed NuGet Package and after that installed AjaxControlToolkit from the package. Downloaded AjaxControlToolkit 4.5 from CodePlex.com. Loaded .dll file to toolbar.

Here is configuration file from web.config

<add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>

Comment: Is there anyone can help me with this? Got stuck in middle of sthg -.-